# Names of internet pages not showing on some PC's

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-10

We use a custom developed piece of software that helps us with our accounts, orders etc.

It is accessed via internet explorer and due to the way it works, only accessible via IE :(

On some systems it displays the name of the page they are on, say accounts, or a customer ID number, on a couple of other computers it only displays the HTML address not the title.

Is there a tickbox or option that turns on/off the page titles displaying or is it not that simple?

All of the PC's are using Windows 7 Professional and all with IE10

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any native way to do this, but, you could use GreaseMonkey for IE (or at least, a port, such as Trixie)

It will let you write some HTML, which effectively overwrites the title. You may require some javascript, it depends on how the code is set up really and where the title comes from as to how easy it will be to write.

Maybe something as easy as

```
title { visibility: hidden; }
```

I doubt you need this but I include it incase the above doesn't work

```
title { display: none; }
```

---

Another option (bullets are part of a quote)

1. maximize the Desktop Window using the shortcut,  and
2. auto-hide the taskbar.  You will still have the address bar and tab bar on top, however.  Otherwise, the Start screen Internet Explorer will provide a full screen view with no tabs, no address bar (but also no taskbar)

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/hide-title-addres-and-tab-bars/5e299149-f5cf-4296-ac30-f23c894ff3cc)

Comment: Dave:

As much as that is a brilliant response. I dont have a clue where to start with that. The problem is that its software that our "Korean" internal IT write up and unfortunately (or fortunately depending on how you look at it haha) they are like trying to get blood from a stone. 

I will try and see if I can get any code from them but its doubtful.
If you have any other ideas please let me know. 

Thanks
Jam

Comment: No, you're missing the point here. Trixie is a plugin for your browser and it will overwrite the code of the website (depends on how it is coded)!

Comment: There is also [Grease Monkey 4 IE](http://web.archive.org/web/20110624002700/http://www.gm4ie.com/)